# Show that $\displaystyle\int_Ef^p=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^pd\omega(\alpha)=p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that f is non-negative and measurable on E and $\omega$ is finite on $(0,\infty)$.

Show that

\begin{aligned}
\int_Ef^p=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^pd\omega(\alpha)=p\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha
\end{aligned}

,where $\omega(\alpha)=|\{x\in E :f(x)>\alpha\}|$, it is the well-known  distribution function of $f$ on $E$.

Remark : here $f$ need not be in $L^p(E)$ and |E|,i.e. the Lebesgue's measure of E need not be finite.

Is there anybody give some idea.I am learning this.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{E}f^{p}(x)d\mu(x)&=\int_{E}\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{t<|f(x)|}(t)pt^{p-1}dtd\mu(x)\\
&=p\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{E}\chi_{t<|f(x)|}(x)d\mu(x)t^{p-1}dt\\
&=p\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu(\{x\in E:t<|f(x)|\})t^{p-1}dt\\
&=p\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{p-1}\omega(t)dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for helping.